# What purpose does `req.options` serve in SailsJS?

Tags: sails.js

What purpose does `req.options` serve in [SailsJs](http://sailsjs.org/)?

From the source, it seems I can somehow use policies to alter existing params on Sails Blueprints, etc. How does this work? I can't find any documentation at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req.options` was introduced in Sails v0.10 as a way to add options to custom routes.  For example, you could always do:

```
'GET /userList': {
    controller: 'UserController', 
    action: 'find'
}
```

to point at the default "find" action for a User model, but there was no way to control the query--it would always just return all records.  Now you can do:

```
'GET /userList': {
    controller: 'UserController', 
    action: 'find',
    sort: 'name desc',
    where: {name: {startsWith: 'j'}}
}
```

and all of the options (including `controller` and `action`) will be added to `req.options`, which the default blueprint actions use to modify the query.  Note the difference to Sails v0.9.x, which used `req.target` to keep track of the controller and action.

As you pointed out, `req.options` can also be modified within policies, as opposed to `req.params` which are reset before every policy and controller action.  This can be used to, for example, further restrict the criteria for a query based on a user's role.

Obviously the docs for v0.10.x aren't completely finished (and will always be subject to improvement), but this could definitely find a place in the [Route Target Syntax](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.md) section...

Comment: Whoa! That's powerful. Any overview available as to what properties (`sort`, `where` ,etc) are used by the various Rest blueprints?

Comment: if you look at the sails/lib/blueprints/actionUtils.js you can see where an how it uses it. I have been playing with it and seems a little limited so far. But i do use req.options.where to limit searches in find and findOne actions. It requires a little rewriting your blueprints.

Comment: What do you mean by "`req.params` reset before every policy". I'm trying to add a default owner in a policy, so in a policy I do, `req.body.owner = me`. It seems to work, is this not the right way of doing it?

Comment: What I mean is that setting `req.params.foo = 123` in one policy will not have any effect in another.  The same isn't the case for `req.body`, and provided that you make sure you're not overriding an existing key, it's a fine option, but `req.options` was created so that you can leave the original request parameters alone if you want to.

Comment: I am reaaaaally curious about where req.options is being set and what all of its capabilities are. I can't find it in the code or in the docs...

Comment: There will be more docs on this in the upcoming release.  You can [preview them here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/tree/v0.11/reference/req/req.options), but they're not exhaustive.